# How to redirect an Alfresco webscript to a different response page

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I've defined an Alfresco Repo Webscript, implemented in Java, which copies a template folder structure into a site's document repository.

The Freemarker HTML template for this webscript is trivial

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Your request was successful</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I don't actually want this to be displayed to the user. I want the response page to be the site's document repository.

So in my Java webscript code, I added this line

```
@Override
protected Map<String, Object> executeImpl(WebScriptRequest req, Status status, Cache cache) {
    ...     
    status.setLocation("http://localhost:8081/share/page/site/my-site/documentlibrary");
    ...
}
```

which I'd hoped would redirect the response to the url, but the page above is still being rendered.

Looking at the code for `DeclarativeWebScript` (which my implementation class inherits from), I see this

```
String location = status.getLocation();
if (location != null && location.length() > 0)
{
  if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
  logger.debug("Setting location to " + location);
  res.setHeader(WebScriptResponse.HEADER_LOCATION, location);
}
```

What am I missing to get the redirect to work?

Comment: Set a redirect code on the status object too?

Comment: Spot on man! status.setCode(302); did the trick. Post it up as an answer and I'll give you the rep points. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer - you need to set a status redirect code too. This is covered in [this somewhat hard to find Alfresco document on Java WebScripts and error handling](http://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/concepts/ws-Java-response.html)

You should add something like:

```
  status.setCode(Status.STATUS_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
```

See also the [Status object javadocs](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/spring-surf-parent/spring-webscripts/spring-webscripts/apidocs/org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/Status.html) and [DeclarativeWebScript](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/spring-surf-parent/spring-webscripts/spring-webscripts/apidocs/org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/DeclarativeWebScript.html)